# Check if a positive semidefinite matrix squared is also positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $K$ is a positive semidefinite matrix, how to prove that $K^2$ is also positive semidefinite?

Thanks.

Comment: Write out the diagonalization, get the result basically for free.

Comment: Counterexample for the "non-symmetric case": $$K= \pmatrix{1&2\\0&1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your $K$ is symmetric/selfadjoint. Then
$$
\langle K^2x,x\rangle = \langle Kx,Kx\rangle = \|Kx\|^2\ge 0.
$$
So, $K$ itself need not be positive semi-definite. $K^2$ always is.

Comment: Why $\langle K^2x,x\rangle \ge 0$ imply that $K^2$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: Because that is the definition.

Comment: Never saw represented in that way, thanks anyway.

Comment: $\langle Ax,x\rangle = x^TAx$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you again!

Comment: Is $A^2$ a positive semidefinite matrix for any matrix $A$ ? If not is there a counter example you know?

Comment: If $A$ is self-adjoint (symmetric), then $A^2$ is always positive semi-definite. If $A$ is not self-adjoint, then $A^2$ is not even self-adjoint and thus not positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be a positive semidefinite matrix, then $\forall \lambda, \lambda \in \sigma(K), \lambda \geq 0$

Then $Kx = \lambda x \implies K(Kx) = K^2x = \lambda Kx = \lambda^2 x $

Let $\mu$ be the set of eigenvalues associated with $K^2$, $\mu = \lambda^2$, then $\mu \geq 0$